# How to pass values from django template to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm trying to send the values from checked radio buttons in django template and get an alert message when the form is submitted.How do use the javascript function to do alert the user?

**This is the django template**

```
<form name="taketest">
        <ul>
        {% for q, opts in quesBank.items %}
                {{ forloop.counter }}{{q}}
                <ol>
                        <label class='radiocontainer'><input type="radio" name="q{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{opts.0}}">{{opts.0}}</input></label><span class='checkmark'>
                        <label class='radiocontainer'><input type="radio" name="q{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{opts.1}}">{{opts.1}}</input></label><span class='checkmark'>
                        <label class='radiocontainer'><input type="radio" name="q{{forloop.counter}}"value="{{opts.2}}">{{opts.2}}</input></label><span class='checkmark'>
                        <label class='radiocontainer'><input type="radio" name="q{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{opts.3}}">{{opts.3}}</input></label><span class='checkmark'>

                </ol>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="text-right">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" onsubmit="return submitAnswers(JSON.parse('answers=[{% for a in correctAnswer %}'{{a|safe}}',{% endfor %}])')">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

**This is the javascript file**

```
function submitAnswers(answers){
  var total = answers.length;
  var score = 0;
  var choice = []

//new dynamic method 1
  for(var i = 1; i <= total; i++){

    choice[i] = document.forms["taketest"]["q"+i].value;
  }
  // new dynamic method 1 for checking answer
  for(i = 1; i <= total; i++){
    if(choice[i] == answers[i]){
      score++;
    }
  }

  //Display Result

  window.alert("You scored " + score + " out of " + total);

  return false;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: I wouldn't say wrong, but it is very old school approach. Nowadays good practices have been established and they differ significantly from your approach. The question is a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: if the code is'nt wrong why is it not working??

Comment: What is exactly not working? Do you get any error message? My comment was about your approach. Fixing any error in this code will still leave you with a solution which is deemed to be bad practice. I'd strongly suggest to take a look at [jQuery](https://jquery.com) or if you want to use vanilla JS take a look at [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener).

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: the javascript function is not being called when i submit the form